# Some touchable opacity works while others do not inside React Native Animated View

Tags: react-native

I am trying to show a new header after the old one collapses while scrolling. Buttons in old header work fine. However, buttons on the new header are not clickable at all.

I have tried the old stack-overflow solution for creating a class for the Animated.View. However, it's not working at all.

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.header, {height: headerHeight}]}>

        <Animated.View style={[styles.mainHeader, {opacity: headerOpacity}]}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goBack} style={{marginTop: 6, height: 25, width: 25}}>
            <Image style={{height: 18, width: 18, tintColor: StyleConstants.pallete.white}} source={require('../assets/images/icon-back.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <AppText size = '24' bold color='white' > {parent_bucket.bucket_name} </AppText>

          {this.renderBucketSetting()}
        </Animated.View>

        <Animated.View  style={[styles.backgroundImage, {opacity: imageOpacity, transform: [{translateY: imageTranslate}]}]}>
          <Image style={styles.backgroundImage} source={{uri : parent_bucket.cover_image}} />

            <View style={styles.coverOverlayContainer}>
              <Faded height={HEIGHT/5} color="#000000" direction="bottom">
                <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 20,  paddingVertical: 35, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goBack} style={{height: 25, width: 25}}>
                    <Image style={{height: 18, width: 18, tintColor: StyleConstants.pallete.white}} source={require('../assets/images/icon-back.png')} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </Faded>
              <Faded height={HEIGHT/5} color="#000000">
                <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 5, paddingVertical: 20, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                  <AppText size = '24' bold color='white' > {parent_bucket.bucket_name} </AppText>
                  {this.renderBucketSetting()}
                </View>
              </Faded>
            </View>
        </Animated.View>

        </Animated.View>
```

```
renderBucketSetting returns

      <BucketSettingsView
        toggleView = {this.toggleView}
        toggleDeleteAlert = {this.toggleDeleteAlert}
        reminder_type = {this.state.reminder_type}
        setMenuRef = {this.setMenuRef}
        showMenu = {this.showMenu}
        menuShare = {this.menuShare}
        menuArchive = {this.menuArchive}
        menuDelete = {this.menuDelete}
        menuEditReminders = {this.menuEditReminders}
      />
```

```
Styles

header: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  backgroundColor: "black",
  overflow: 'hidden',
},
scrollViewContent: {
  marginTop: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT,
},
backgroundImage: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  width: null,
  height: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT,
  resizeMode: 'cover',
},
mainHeader: {
  flex:1,
  flexDirection: "row",
  justifyContent:"space-between",
  marginLeft: 20,
  marginTop:30
}
```

```
  const headerHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
    outputRange: [HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    const imageOpacity = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE / 2, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
      outputRange: [1, 1, 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    const headerOpacity = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE / 2, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
      outputRange: [0, 0, 1],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    const imageTranslate = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
      outputRange: [0, -50],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });
```

Expected Result: Buttons on both Animated View should work.

Actual Result: Buttons on first Animated.View (rendered by this.renderBucketSetting()) is not clickable. However, buttons on the second Animated.View(also rendered by this.renderBucketSetting()) is working perfectly. However, if I switch the position of both Animated.View, the result is vice-versa (old header button does not work, and new header buttons work).

Answer (score 0):

Probably because since you are using absolute positions one view goes above the other and that cancels the touches.

If you actually want to solve this, it involves using the PanResponder and handling the touches manually: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder

You would need to add a pan responder to each View, and pass the touches to the other. I have to be honest, I am having issues trying to imagine what is that you want to achieve so I can give you a better answer.

Cheers

Comment: Well, at first I had two headers, one at the bottom of a background image (which took 1/3 of the view), and second at the top of the view. Initially, the top header had opacity 0, and bottom header had opacity 1. My initial goal was to hide the bottom header and show the top header when a user scrolls up. Although both headers shared the same component, buttons inside the top header would not respond. However, I just deleted the top header and gave animation to the bottom header. So when a user scrolls up, it will reduce the distance of bottom header from the top, and nicely fit at the top.

Comment: Thanks anyways sfratini. Panresonder seems to be awesome. However, as someone starting out with RN animations, I will definitely have to invest more time to go through its obscure and cryptic documentation.